# Firefox browser is not opening with selenium webbrowser code

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, firefox

Need guidance and help in the below one.

When the below code is executed, I am getting error. I am using the latest version of java, eclipse, firefox, and WebDrive jar file.

```
package firsttest1;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class helloselenium {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver;
        driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        String url ="http://www.google.com";
        driver.get(url);
    }
}
```

**error....**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases 
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
>       at     org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:38)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:91)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:245)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:220)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:215)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
>       at firsttest1.helloselenium.main(helloselenium.java:12)

Version used:
eclipse : neon version
java : jdk1.8 
fire fox: v48
WebDrive jar file : v 3.0.0 beta2

guide me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 42):

You are using latest version of `Selenium WebDriver` i.e. `Selenium 3.x`, this version of webdriver doesn't support direct firefox launch. You have to set the `SystemProperty` for `webdriver.gecko.driver`.

Replace the Code:-

```
WebDriver driver;
driver =new FirefoxDriver();
```

With This code:-

```
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<Path to your WebDriver>");
driver =new FirefoxDriver();
```

You can get the information about latest changes [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG)

You can download the latest `Gecko` driver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: I'm using windows/Eclipse/Selenium --> Adding: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe"); --> I get an error on this line saying: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Comment: Resolved the problem if it helps someone using double backward slash: "C:\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe"

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this using the Seleniumhq jenkins plugin?

Comment: Finally it worked!!! 



I was on version 51 for FF and selenium 3.0. I had to downgrade from 51 to 47 and added the 'client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar' and finally: 


`WebDriver driver;` `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\kul\\geckod‌​‌​river.exe");` `drive‌​r = new FirefoxDriver();` `driver.get("[google.com](http://google.com)");`

Answer (score 8):

Download the lastest version for geckoDriver [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) then set a System property called "webdriver.gecko.driver" and put on it the path to your geckoDriver executable path
`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<path to your gecko driver executable>");`

Answer (score 2):

Firefox driver is based on [marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette) starting with Selenium 3.0. Unlike, 2.x versions, it requires an external executable file. You should add it to your path. For more information, you should have a look at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver.

Comment: this worked for me