# java.lang.IllegalStateException -- in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I am trying to execute a basic test program with Selenium framework in Eclipse, but I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` error. I have added all the `jar` files and I am using Selenium 3.0.0 beta (Java).

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

**This is the error I am facing:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: F:\JAVA\WebDriverTest1\<C Users MANOJ 6 Downloads gecko>
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:38)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:244)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:219)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:210)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:123)
at Test1.Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751525/firefox-browser-is-not-opening-with-selenium-webbrowser-code

Comment: Can you please add the full stack trace?  All I can tell you with what you've posted is that some state, somewhere, is illegal.

Comment: I have added gecko driver but it is not working either.
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<C Users MANOJ 6 Downloads gecko>");

Comment: Also i tried it converting into maven project by adding selenium dependencies but even that didn't worked

Comment: @manojreddy instead of `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<C Users MANOJ 6 Downloads gecko>");` Try: `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\\\Users\\MANOJ 6\\Downloads\\gecko");`

Comment: @CoryShay thanks, i've tried that but it is still showing the same exception

Comment: @manojreddy, Well it is attempting to find the file for your gecko driver and failing because the file doesn't exist. Therefore, if your driver is within your downloads file you will need to set it to the path of it including extension. For more information see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38676858/6061947).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail to Launch Mozilla with selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium)