# Exception running with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I just installed Selenium WebDriver. When I run, I got the following exception.
Can anyone help me how to fix it Please?

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:**
>
> The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\Owner\workspace\Second
>   Time Jave Project\path of\geckodriver.exe     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:37)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:95)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:135)
>     at secondTimePackage.NewJavaClass.main(NewJavaClass.java:17)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox browser is not opening with selenium webbrowser code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751525/firefox-browser-is-not-opening-with-selenium-webbrowser-code)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed your web driver? Once you do, you'll need to set your system property:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "[your file path to your web driver here]");
```

before you call your new Firefox Driver.

Looks like you're having the a similar problem to this question:
[Firefox browser is not opening with selenium webbrowser code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751525/firefox-browser-is-not-opening-with-selenium-webbrowser-code)

Answer (score 0):

first check the driver version should be updated with the selenium version
then The easiest way to upload the files instead calling the path from ur pc

{
string path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\sources\chromedriver.exe";

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path);

  ChromeDriver  driver= new ChromeDriver();
```

}