# Selenium Web Driver script for login page results in an error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code:

```
package pak0310;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class class0310 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // objects and variables instantiation
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
        // launch the firefox browser and open the application url
        driver.get(appUrl);
        // maximize the browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // declare and initialize the variable to store the expected title of the webpage.
        String expectedTitle = " Sign in - Google Accounts ";
        // fetch the title of the web page and save it into a string variable
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        // compare the expected title of the page with the actual title of the page and print the result
        if (expectedTitle.equals(actualTitle))
              {
                 System.out.println("Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.");
              }
        else
              {
                 System.out.println("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");
              }
        // enter a valid username in the email textbox
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys("TestSelenium");
        // enter a valid password in the password textbox
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys("password123");
        WebElement SignInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
        SignInButton.click();
        // close the web browser
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("Test script executed successfully.");
        // terminate the program
        System.exit(0);
       }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at pak0310.class0310.main(class0310.java:22)
...
```

Comment: See this QA [**`Why Firefox requires GeckoDriver?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver/43661697#43661697)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Java - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr)

Answer (score 0):

This error suggesting to use of geckodriver (post Selenium 3), to launch Firefox. You can refer

[How to use the gecko executable with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785686/how-to-use-the-gecko-executable-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

In this similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38752315/8195985) user Paras answered:

*You are using latest version of Selenium WebDriver i.e. Selenium 3.x, this version of webdriver doesn't support direct firefox launch. You have to set the SystemProperty for webdriver.gecko.driver.*

Replace the Code:-

```
WebDriver driver; =new FirefoxDriver();
```

With This code:-

```
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<Path to your WebDriver>");
driver =new FirefoxDriver();
```

Maybe use that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
2. unzip folder you will get like this geckodriver.exe
3. Copy that paste in some where and copy the complete path with driver.
4. use below code in `<path>` place paste your path

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "your path");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Please make an effort to format your posts appropriately. In particular, angle tags such as `<path>` are **invisible** unless you backtick them. Use the preview feature!